# What is the right derived functor of $\lim_\leftarrow$?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence, functors

Suppose we are talking about $\lim_\leftarrow$ on category of abelian groups. By definition, the right derived functor of $\lim_\leftarrow$ would be $R_1\lim_\leftarrow \{G_n\}=\text{Ker } \lim_\leftarrow d_1/\text{Im} \lim_\leftarrow d_{2}$ for every $\{G_n\}\in \mathbf{Fun}(\mathbb N,\text{Ab})$, where $$0\rightarrow \{G_n\}\stackrel{d_0}{\longrightarrow}\mathbf{G_1}\stackrel{d_1}{\longrightarrow}\mathbf{G_2}\stackrel{d_2}{\longrightarrow}...$$ is the, well, I don't know what it is called (maybe injective resolution?). It is an exact sequence and each $\mathbf G_n$ satisfies that for any $\mathbb Z$-module $A,B$ and injection $f:A\to B$ and $\sigma\in \text{Hom}(A,\mathbf G_n)$, there is a $\tau\in \text{Hom}(B,\mathbf{G_n})$ making $\tau\circ f=\sigma$.

Howevery, to make this definition meaningful, $\{G_n\}\in \mathbf{Fun}(\mathbb N,\text{Ab})$ needs to be a $\mathbb Z$-module. But how can it be a $\mathbb Z$-module? Am I misunderstanding something? (About the definition of $\lim^1$)

Comment: I might be misunderstanding/misremembering, but if $\lim_{\leftarrow}$ is a functor from $\mathbf{Fun}(\mathbb{N}, \mathrm{AB})$ to $\mathrm{Ab}$ then shouldn't our injective resolution be in $\mathbf{Fun}(\mathbb{N}, \mathrm{AB})$?

Comment: @memerson It should?

Comment: Generally when we define we have a left exact functor $F:\mathcal A \to \mathcal B$, then to find the right derived functor $R$ applied to $X$, we take an injective resolution $X \to I_1 \to I_2 \to \dots$ in $\mathcal A$, apply $F$ to it and then take the cohomology of the resulting chain complex. Thus if we view $\lim_{\rightarrow}$ as an object in  $\mathbf{Fun}(\mathbb N,$Ab), our injective resolution must be in Ab as well.

Comment: @memerson so $\mathbf{G_n}$ don't need to be injective objects in $\mathbb Z$ module but need to be injective objects in $\mathbf {Fun}(\mathbb N,\text{Ab})$? I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case there is a standard 2-step resolution which may not be injective, precisely, but which suffices to compute the derived functor. You can read about it [on the nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lim%5E1+and+Milnor+sequences), for example.

Note that we're talking about resolutions and injectivity *in the category of inverse systems of abelian groups*. So the resolution is really a chain complex of inverse systems -- maybe a bit more data than you were expecting.